# In reactjs while click on button decrement count one time only again we click on that same button we don't want decrement

Tags: reactjs

While click on button decrement count one time only again we will click on same button count will not decrement

I tried printing count by clicking count continuously changes I don't want that continuous printing the count

Comment: Don't increment 'the counter', but keep track of a boolean indicating if the button has been pressed.

Comment: Hi Sneha, it might be better if you also include a code snippet to help us further understand the issue. You could do that through the "Edit" button below the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add a state to track, when to stop decrement

```
const [stopDecrementing, setStopDecrementing] = useState(false);

const onDecrementBtnClick = () => {
   // wrap your existing logic with a condition
   if(!stopDecrementing){
      // your existing logic as it is
   }
   // plz add this at the end
   setStopDecrementing(true)
}
```